# Inheritance and Implicit Type Casting

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following three classes:

```
class Animal {};

class Human : public Animal {};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
   void setOwner(Animal* owner) { this->owner = owner; }
private:
   Animal* owner;
};
```

Why is the following allowed, and what exactly is happening?

```
Dog d;
Human h;

d.setOwner(&h); // ?
```

At first, I tried to cast it like this `d.setOwner(&(Animal)h)`, but the compiler gave me a warning, and I hit a run-time error.

**Edit**: the warning the compiler gave me was "taking address of temporary". Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here
    d.setOwner((Animal)&h)

you try to case pointer type to object type. You cannnot do this.

Correct way of casting to Animal class is

```
d.setOwner((Animal*)&h)
```

But you

This

```
d.setOwner(&h);
```

works because pointers in C++ are automatically cast to a base class if needed. Explicit conversion to Animal* is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no type casting, but a `Human` **is-an** `Animal`. So any interface that acts on a `Animal*` will accept a `Human*`. The same applies to `Animal&` and `Human&`. Of course, they only see the `Animal` part of the object's interface.

Answer (score 1):

As the others pionted out there is no need to cast a derived* to base*

but nobody answerd the question to the warning.
yes, there was a temporary Animal created. instead of casting the pointer you casted the object itself from Human owner to Animal. this caused a temporary Animal to be created from the Human owner. the address of this temporary was passed to the set function. when the setter returnes the temporary Human disappers an the poor Dogs owner pointer is invalid.

so always read the warnings. if you do not understand them consider them to be errors.

another issue - avoid constructor elements and members to have identical names or one day you will learn this rule the hard way.